# How do I modify the jQuery aToolTip plugin to "flip" to left when approaching the right margin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flip, tooltip

I am using aToolTip and need to have the tooltips flip from a normal lower left placement, to a right placement to keep them from going off the page.

I did a little research, and with a little help, I was able to modify the code to a little to allow for a working "flip" on a single image.  The image is referred to as hat_icon, and that code is below:

```
        $(function() {

            //$("#wrap a[title]").tooltips();
            //$("#page-wrap a[title]").tooltips();

        //    $('a').aToolTip({  
        //    $('a').aToolTip({       
     $("a:not(.tooltipquestion, .accountnav, #hat_icon)").aToolTip({ 
        // no need to change/override  
        closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',  
        toolTipId: 'aToolTip',  
        // ok to override  
        //   fixed: false,                   // Set true to activate fixed position  
        fixed: false,                   // Set true to activate fixed position   -- chris/peter 12/9
        clickIt: false,                 // set to true for click activated tooltip  
        //   inSpeed: 200,                   // Speed tooltip fades in  
        inSpeed: 400,                   // Speed tooltip fades in   --chris/peter 12/9
        outSpeed: 400,                  // Speed tooltip fades out  
        tipContent: '',                 // Pass in content or it will use objects 'title' attribute  
        toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',   // Set class name for custom theme/styles  
        xOffset: 15,                     // x position  
        yOffset: -50,                     // y position  
        onShow: null,                   // callback function that fires after atooltip has shown  
        onHide: null                    // callback function that fires after atooltip has faded out      
    });

    jQuery('a.accountnav,#hat_icon').hover(function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#aToolTip').css({'border-radius':'12px 0 12px 12px'});
        }, 1000);
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#aToolTip').css({'border-radius':'12px 12px 12px 0'});
        },500);
    });

    jQuery('a.accountnav,#hat_icon').aToolTip({

        fixed: false,
        xOffset: -250,
        yOffset: -50, 
    });
    jQuery('#hat_icon').aToolTip({

        fixed: false,
        xOffset: -250,
        yOffset: -80, 
    });

});
```

I know there is a way to detect collision using something like position: (collision: "flipfit flip"), but I do not know how to implement it properly.  Can you help me?

Comment: Also, I need to show this custom tooltip in spans to allow for the new style; however, currently it only shows in links.  How do I modify it?

Answer (score 1):

**To flip**

Find this:

```
$('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
    top: (el.pageY - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset),
    left: (el.pageX + settings.xOffset)
});
```

And replace by this:

```
A_TOP = (el.pageY - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset);
if(A_TOP<0){
    A_TOP = 40;
}
A_LEFT = (el.pageX + settings.xOffset);
WindowWidth = ($(window).width()-$('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerWidth());
if(A_LEFT>WindowWidth){
     A_LEFT -= $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerWidth();
}
$('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
    top: A_TOP,
    left: A_LEFT,
    whiteSpace:"nowrap"
});
```